# Conditionals based on perceived gender

Tags: css, cookies, browser

Is it possible to use data stored in cookies or from a web browser to determine if a website's visitor is male or female.

I'd like to use this sort of data to style my site with a different color scheme for males.

Comment: You could store any data (less than 4KB) in cookie. However, I'd like to know how you determine the gender of the visitor.

Comment: Is it possible using some data from Google Analytics, for instance?

Comment: I think you may have cookies confused with magic beans there... A cookie is just a text file stored by, and readable by, *a particular server*. Unless that server happens to be a massively popular ad host (i.e. Google) you're going to have trouble getting out something the user hasn't told you yet.

Comment: You would have find some way to prompt that information from them and store that. Otherwise, outside of highly suspicious data mining activities or statistical guesswork, no chance.

Comment: NW Tech, if your question is about Google Analytics, then try it, and let us know if you get stuck on something.

Comment: Google's able to use it to serve ads, I was hopeful there was a way that we could harness that same data to serve content as well: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2580383

Comment: @NWTech Yep, that's because *they run the ads*, which is why I mentioned them already. You could try approaching Google and asking to buy their database of user profiles, but since they're a) a core asset of their business, and b) covered by strict privacy policies, probably best not to hold your breath.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: **please don't do this, even if you can**. Stereotyping something like a colour scheme based on perceived gender is a horribly condescending idea. How about instead, you let the user pick their own colour scheme?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know the user's gender for a fact (they could lie; I know many people who do often during registrations to maintain anonymity); but you can estimate based on browser history.

One person created a little hack where you can estimate gender by browser history:
http://www.mikeonads.com/2008/07/13/using-your-browser-url-history-estimate-gender/

**QUOTE:**

> ... modified the SocialHistory JS so that it polled the browser to find out which of the Quantcast top 10k sites were visited. I then apply the ratio of male to female users for each site and with some basic math determine a guestimate of your gender. The math is really quite simple, I just take: 
>   `1 / (1 + r_1 * r_2 * … * r_n)`
>
> where p_i is the ratio of men-to-women for the specific site. For example, if you had been to two sites that had a 2-1 ratio of men to women, the probability of you being female would be:
>   `1 / (1 + 2 * 2) = 1/5 = 20%`

If you had access to users' browser history you may be able to derive some method to estimate their gender.

Google Analytics also estimates gender, as well as Quantcast, others, and many cpanel software like awstats.

Users sometimes store their gender in local profiles on their PC, but without illegal spyware to sniff users, there is no clean legal way to gather this information which may or may not be stored in cookies in their browser based on the websites they registered for or are logged into which gathered their gender during registration.

Of course the very illegal way to be certain would be to access the webcam using illegal malware and then using facial recognition software you could set up an automated software to accurately determine the gender of every person who has a laptop or pc with a webcam. However unless you're some crazy hacker with no worries about getting arrested then I would avoid trying this if I were you.

Comment: Personally I'd just let the users choose the color they like from a predetermined menu. You'd save yourself the trouble of possibly offending someone for assuming a color for them just because of their gender.

Comment: I was about to add that same thing. Also consider that gender-based color preferences are cultural not inherent. For example, the US blue is boy and pink is girl, but in some asian countries, pink is boy and blue is girl. Many people don't know this.

Comment: The blog post you link to relies on a hack which was fixed by browsers several years ago as a privacy leak: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sadly though many people still use some ancient browser and probably never upgraded.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I would assume that things like Google Analytics will only give you *aggregated trends* about things like gender, not the gender of a specific user as would be required here. If Google gave any site access to the full profile of every visitor, that would surely be a massive violation of their privacy policies.